# TornadoFX: Allow copying an item from a listview to clipboard

Tags: kotlin, copy-paste, tornadofx

When an item in a listview is selected, I would like the user to be able to copy the content to the clipboard. How can I achieve that?

Comment: It would be the same as working with any other clipboard data (https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx/blob/4131322397b9907d6b9a63bc83e0a5ac2a9e1871/src/test/kotlin/tornadofx/tests/ClipboardTest.kt). You just need to get the selected item add it.

Comment: I'm particularely interested in how to install the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: You could use the `shortcut(KeyCombination, () -> Unit)` function to install the keyboard shortcut, which would get the selected item from the list and add it to the clipboard. (https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx/blob/bc2efd7496aa4338438089d25318554a6698a8f9/src/main/java/tornadofx/Component.kt#L617)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a shortcut to the view like so

```
shortcut(KeyCombination.valueOf("Ctrl+C")) {
    // Convert the selected item as you see fit and add it to the clipboard
    // For example:
    clipboard.put(MyCustomFormat, listview.selectedItem)
}
```